# cv::Mat.release()

Tags: c++, opencv

I am start using OpenCV in my image processing program.
When I use `cv::Mat` and allocate in a method on the memory as:

```
cv::Mat coords(100, 5, CV_32FC1);
```

Do I need to do `coords.release()` to clear from the memory at the end of the method if I don't need anymore?

Is that have to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to explicitly release the `cv::Mat` object. `cv::Mat` object will automatically be released (i.e. its destructor would be called), once it goes out of the scope in which it was declared.

### Update:

(In response to the comment)

To check if the `cv::Mat` has been successfully allocated, you can do the following:

```
cv::Mat coords(100, 5, CV_32FC1); 

if(coords.empty())
{
   cout<<"Matrix Not Allocated";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, say if I allocate the memory for cv::Mat coords(100, 5, CV_32FC1); do I need to detect coords.ptr is successfully allocated or not like if(!coords.ptr) return 0; Should I do that